# Python Dictionary showing empty values when adding lists

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm trying to produce a JSON format for a given entity and I'm having an issue getting the dictionary to NOT overwrite itself or become empty.  This is pulling rows from a table in a MySQL database and attempting to produce JSON result from the query.

Here is my function:

```py
def detail():
    student = 'John Doe'
    conn = get_db_connection()
    cur = conn.cursor()
    sql = ("""
             select
                a.student_name,
                a.student_id,
                a.student_homeroom_name,
                a.test_id,
                a.datetaken, 
                a.datecertified,
                b.request_number
                FROM student_information a 
                INNER JOIN homeroom b ON a.homeroom_id = b.homeroom_id
                WHERE a.student_name = '""" + student + """'
                ORDER BY datecertified DESC 
             """)
    cur.execute(sql)
    details=cur.fetchall()
    
    dataset = defaultdict(dict)
    case_dataset = defaultdict(dict)
    case_dataset = dict(case_dataset)
    
    for student_name, student_id, student_homeroom_name, test_id, datetaken, datecertified, request_number in details:
        dataset[student_name]['student_id'] = student_id
        dataset[student_name]['student_homeroom_name'] = student_homeroom_name
        
        case_dataset['test_id'] = test_id
        case_dataset['datetaken'] = datetaken
        case_dataset['datecertified'] = datecertified
        case_dataset['request_number'] = request_number

        dataset[student_name]['additional_information'] = case_dataset

        case_dataset.clear()
    
    dataset= dict(dataset)
    print(dataset)

    cur.close()
    conn.close()
```

I tried a few different ways but nothing seems to work.  What I'm getting is nothing in the `additonal_information` key.  What I'm getting is this:

```json
{
    "John Doe": {
        "student_id": "1234",
        "student_homeroom_name": "HR1",
        "additional_information": []
    }
}
```

What I'm expecting is something similar to the below JSON. However, I'm torn if this is even correct.  Each student will have one to many `test_id` and I will need to iterate through them in my application.

```json
{
    "John Doe": {
        "student_id": "1234",
        "student_homeroom_name": "HR1",
        "additional_information": [
                {
                    "test_id": "0987",
                    "datetaken": "1-1-1970",
                    "datecertified": "1-2-1970",
                    "request_number": "5643"
                },
                {
                    "test_id": "12343",
                    "datetaken": "1-1-1980",
                    "datecertified": "1-2-1980",
                    "request_number": "39807"
                }
        ]
    }
}
```

Removing the `clear()` from the function produces this JSON:

```
{
    "John Doe": {
        "student_id": "1234",
        "student_homeroom_name": "HR1",
        "additional_information": [
            {
                "test_id": "0987",
                "datetaken": "1-1-1970",
                "datecertified": "1-2-1970",
                "request_number": "5643"
            },
            {
                "test_id": "0987",
                "datetaken": "1-1-1970",
                "datecertified": "1-2-1970",
                "request_number": "5643"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you add stuff to `additional_dataset` and `case_dataset` and then immediately clear them?

Comment: Great Question.  This was an attempt to ensure that the correct data was getting loaded and not replaced.  I had an issue where the last row of data was replacing all data in the `for` loop.  I thought clearing the datasets would help.  When I remove those rows, I get two lists of the same data.

Comment: I updated the question with what I see when I remove the `clear()` from the function.

Comment: @khelwood: At least they store `case_dataset` (even if aliasing means the `clear` empties that copy). `additional_dataset` seems to serve no purpose, it's repeatedly populated and cleared and *never* used.

Comment: @ShadowRanger - This is a good point.  I removed the code from the question.  It was a pervious attempt to diagnose the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for the guidance and pointing me in the right direction.

I have what I'm looking for now.  Based on some of the comments and troubleshooting, I updated my code.  Here is what I did:

1. I added back `additional_dataset` as a list
2. Removed `case_dataset = defaultdict(dict)` and `case_dataset = dict(case_dataset)` and replaced it with `case_dataset = {}`.
3. Updated `dataset[student_name]['additional_information'] = case_dataset` with `dataset[student_name]['additional_information'] = additional_dataset`
4. Replaced `case_dataset.clear()` with `case_dataset = {}`

Here is my new code now

```
def detail():
    student = 'John Doe'
    conn = get_db_connection()
    cur = conn.cursor()
    sql = ("""
             select
                a.student_name,
                a.student_id,
                a.student_homeroom_name,
                a.test_id,
                a.datetaken, 
                a.datecertified,
                b.request_number
                FROM student_information a 
                INNER JOIN homeroom b ON a.homeroom_id = b.homeroom_id
                WHERE a.student_name = '""" + student + """'
                ORDER BY datecertified DESC 
             """)
    cur.execute(sql)
    details=cur.fetchall()
    
    dataset = defaultdict(dict)
    case_dataset = {} #2 - Updated to just dict
    additional_dataset = [] #1 - added back additional_dataset as a list
    
    for student_name, student_id, student_homeroom_name, test_id, datetaken, datecertified, request_number in details:
        dataset[student_name]['student_id'] = student_id
        dataset[student_name]['student_homeroom_name'] = student_homeroom_name
        
        case_dataset['test_id'] = test_id
        case_dataset['datetaken'] = datetaken
        case_dataset['datecertified'] = datecertified
        case_dataset['request_number'] = request_number

        dataset[student_name]['additional_information'] = additional_dataset #3 - updated to additional_dataset

        case_dataset = {} #4 - updated to clear with new dict
    
    dataset= dict(dataset)
    print(dataset)

    cur.close()
    conn.close()
```

This is what it produces now.  This is a much better structure then what I was previously expecting.

```
{
    "John Doe": {
        "student_id": "1234",
        "student_homeroom_name": "HR1",
        "additional_information": [
            {
                "test_id": "0987",
                "datetaken": "1-1-1970",
                "datecertified": "1-2-1970",
                "request_number": "5643"
            },
            {
                "test_id": "12343",
                "datetaken": "1-1-1980",
                "datecertified": "1-2-1980",
                "request_number": "39807"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

lists are mutable objects. Which means that list's are passed by reference.

when you set

```
dataset[student]['additional_information'] = case_dataset

case_dataset.clear()
```

you're setting the list and then clearing it. So the list inside `additional_information` is also cleared.

Copy the list when setting it:

```
dataset[student]['additional_information'] = case_dataset[:]

case_dataset.clear()
```

Comment: `case_dataset` appears to be a `dict`, not a `list`. Regardless, simpler than copying is just replacing it with a new `dict` or `list`. `.clear()` is dangerous, and it's not actually saving you anything (it's more expensive to copy and clear than just store the current version and rebind to a cheap new empty object), so it's simpler to avoid it.

Comment: I get the following `TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice' `

Comment: If I replace `case_dataset[:]` with `additional_dataset[:]` then `additional_dataset` is empty in the JSON output.

Comment: I realized that `additional_dataset` was pervious code from attempts to resolve the issue, so my attempt here to replace `case_default[:]` with `additional_dataset[:]` didn't serve a purpose.  I removed the `additional_dataset` from the queston.

Comment: @RobertThompson: Yeah, they thought it was a `list` (where slicing works). `case_dataset.copy()` is how you shallow copy a `dict`. But really, don't do it. Assign `case_dataset` the way you were originally doing so, and change `case_dataset.clear()` to just `case_dataset = {}` (rebinding it to a brand-new `dict`).